# Sqoop Export from HDFS to Crate.io DB With No Error/Output

Tags: sqoop, crate

I'm trying to export my hdfs to Crate.io DB and I'm using Sqoop to do it.
I've imported the required .jar files and my sqoop file looks like:

```
export
--connect
jdbc:crate://<SERVER-IP>:4200/

--driver
io.crate.client.jdbc.CrateDriver

--table
test

--export-dir
/to/file/in/hdfs

--input-fields-terminated-by
','

--columns
name, age
```

My sqoop operation runs without any error, but there's nothing from my hdfs getting inserted into the crate db.
I've tried mentioning "doc" in the IP but still no success.

```
--connect
jdbc:crate://<SERVER-IP>:4200/doc
```

And alternatively used

```
--table
doc.test
```

I've been able to insert content into crate through the Python Library, but not through Sqoop.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Python uses HTTP, which is why it works via 4200, CrateDB's JDBC driver (v1.x) uses 4300, CrateDB's JDBC driver v2.x uses port 5432
Thus:
jdbc:crate://<SERVER-IP>:4300/doc or jdbc:crate://<SERVER-IP>:5432/doc

Answer (score 1):

You are using port 4200 which is exposed as HTTP port. Since Crate 0.57 you have access via postges protocol (5432). Prior 0.57 you need to use tcp 4300 for jdbc

Comment: Hi @Michael I tried changing my port to 5432 and opened it up on the instance. Still not able to get inserted. I'm even testing with a normal csv with just one column comma separated to see if it goes up. Nothing.

Comment: @jacob can you try and see if any of sqoops queries reach CrateDB? https://crate.io/docs/reference/en/latest/best_practice/systables.html#step-2-activity-in-the-cluster

Also, is the table already created or do you rely on sqoop for that?

Comment: @claus nothing seems to be reaching CrateDB from sqoop, that's why I though changing the port would be an appropriate fix. The table is already created in Sqoop and I'm only trying to insert values into it.

Comment: @AugmentedJacob any logs that you can provide us? It's difficult for us to get a solution here.